# Deleted personal information - favorites, browser history, Zoom, skype, teams, discord

Tags: 20.04

A friend just told me about this problem:

With her account, she lost:

- favorite folders
- browser history
- passwords for Zoom, Skype, Teams, Discord

After a restart:

- the passwords are back
- the other are still lost

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Lost them where?   was she using a terminal and when she entered `ls` they weren't there? or how? and where were they located? ($HOME or elsewhere? given you mention many folders and we cannot know her tastes and thus what she'd see as a 'favorite') What browser was she using?  Your question currently lacks any specifics.

Comment: @guiverc 
When you open Files you have Favorite folders in left column, you can add here. The passwords, I mean - the saved passwords for each application. If I open Skype, I have my details saved here. She lost them.

I don't know where Ubuntu saves these information by default, but it seems it has problem accessing them.

Comment: What was the last thing she did before this happened?

Comment: She used Teams for a call, then shut down the laptop. Today when she opened it she had this problem.